# React Native: Show/Hide <Text> component by toggling icon button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a component which will have a list of  components with data passed in through props.

However when the user first views the screen I'd like the text to be hidden by default and display an eight underscores,  but when the user clicks an icon the text data passed in through props will be displayed.

Take the following example below for instance:

Data:

```
const data = {
First,
Second,
Third,
Fourth
}
```

Default Screen:

```
<View>
<Icon onPress()/>
<ul>
<li>
<Text>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ </Text
</li>
<li>
<Text>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ </Text
</li>
<li>
<Text>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ </Text
</li>
<li>
<Text>_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ </Text
</li>
</ul>
</View>
```

After Pressing:

```
<View>
<Icon onPress()/>
<ul>
<li>
<Text> First </Text
</li>
<li>
<Text> Second </Text
</li>
<li>
<Text> Third </Text
</li>
<li>
<Text> Fourth </Text
</li>
</ul>
</View>
```

I am still new to React, particularly with manipulating state and am wondering how one could achieve something like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a toggle to show or hide your texts.

Example here:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native'

const data = [
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third",
    "Forth"
]

export default props => {

    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false)
    const toggleText = () => setShow(show => !show)

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text onPress={toggleText}>Toggle</Text>
            {
                data.map((text,index) =>
                    <Text key={index}>
                    {show ? text : "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"}
                    </Text>
                )
            }
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Comment: This worked - such a simple solution.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ul` and `li` in react-native, try [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html).
You can use `useState` and conditional rendering.

```js
const data = [
First,
Second,
Third,
Fourth
];

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


return (
<View>
      <Icon onPress={() => setShow(true)}/>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text> {show ?  item : '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'} </Text>}
      />
</View>
)
```